# How to get instance type of generic variable

Tags: kotlin, generics

How can I get the instance type of a generic variable `T`? For instance, assume I have a generic class, I want to:

```
if (T is String) {
    // Do something
}
if (T is Int) {
    // Do something 
}
// etc
```

This gives a `Type parameter 'T' is not an expression` error.

Comment: What do you want to model? Maybe there is a better solution than trying to check the type parameter

Comment: I am trying to initialize a cache, and the cache serialiser is dependent on the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `T::class == String::class`, but it requires the [type to be reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), because otherwise type erasure means there is no type at runtime.

Or a more concise version (that's a little odd and maybe not as clear) is to check if some predefined instance of the type you want matches. This of course still requires a reified type. And this doesn't have the exact same meaning as above when there is a type hierarchy or interfaces involved.

```
if ("" is T) {
    // Do something
}
if (0 is T) {
    // Do something 
}
```